# Datasource of all scheduled news events for S&P 500 stocks

Tags: data, market-data

I am looking for a datasource which contains all news events specific to equities of the S&P 500, whose release date was scheduled in advance. That is, I am not looking for surprise news. For example, earnings announcement dates are scheduled.

Do you know where I could obtain that data?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're able and willing to pay for this data?

Comment: willing yes, able to some extend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for data providers, not Bloomberg, they tend to concentrate on specific events. E.g. for earnings/dividends dates Wall Street Horizon is a standard choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can pay for a Bloomberg terminal subscription which has all these events in API form.